# Scroll to top after clicking link react native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem, which I have no ideas, how to solve. In my react native project I display a list of data and few links at the bottom. After clicking on any of these links it navigates to same page with new data fetched for the clicked link, but the problem is the page never scroll to the top, its position remains the same or sometimes at the middle.

The class ArticleLink :

```
export default class ArticleLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.scrollView = null;
         this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null,
      isError: false,
  }
}

  render() {
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

if(params!=null) {
   getArticleLinks(params.nid).then(data => {
      this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
    data: data
      })
  }, error => {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Something happend, please try again")
  }
)
}
```

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
            <Left>
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon name='arrow-left' size={20} color="white" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}/>
              </Button>
              </Left>
            <Body><Image  style={{ marginTop: 20,backgroundColor: 'white' }} source={IMAGE.ICON_MENU2} style={{ height:35,width:125 }}/></Body>
            <Right>
            </Right>
          </Header>
      <View style={{ marginLeft: 15,flex: 1,fontFamily:'Tageblatt Picto', flexDirection: 'column',  justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>

--------------
------------
----------

  <List  style={{marginBottom:50}}
              dataArray={links}
          renderItem={({item})=>{
              return (
                        <ListItem style={{marginLeft: 0}} noBorder>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ArticleLink',item)} style={{flexDirection:'row'}} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                        <Text  numberOfLines={3} style={{fontSize: 16 }} numberOfLines={2}>{`\u25A0 ${item.title}`}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                      </ListItem>
                    )
              }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to top by adding a ref to your `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView ref={(ref) => { this.scrollView = ref; }}>
```

And when you press on a link you should call

```
this.scrollView.scrollTo(0)
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to scroll to top slowly?